# Problems loading Rcmdr related with Xcode

Tags: r, xcode, macos

I installed the package BiodiversityR in my work computer and I'm having trouble when loading it. It's a problem related with "otool" in Rcmdr: I get a pop-up window urging me to install Xcode (see image attached
). Do I absolutely need to install Xcode? I have BiodiversityR working fine in my home computer, without Xcode...

Anyway, I did try to install Xcode in this computer, but when I load BiodiversityR or Rcmdr, R completely bugs and I have to force to quit.

I have updated R, XQuartz... and still not working. What can I do?

Message when loading BiodiversityR or Rcmdr

[image]

Comment: It might be easier for many answerers if you could kindly switch the language to English for the screenshot of the alert. Personally I wish I knew more languages!

Comment: R sometimes needs the Command Line Tools (for compilers), which can be installed through XCode. However, you can [install them separately](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/how-to-download-the-command-line-tools-for-xcode-without-the-downloads-for-devel).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can only read in English, but from the looks of things you need the OS X command line tools.

[You don't need Xcode to get the command line tools](http://mac-how-to.wonderhowto.com/how-to/install-command-line-developer-tools-without-xcode-0168115/). If the pop-up is similar to the one in [step 3](http://mac-how-to.wonderhowto.com/how-to/install-command-line-developer-tools-without-xcode-0168115/), then it looks like it is presenting the option to install the tool(s) without Xcode anyway (Instalar), and offering the option to "Obtener Xcode" separately.

Thus, if your work computer will let you install just the tool(s), you won't need Xcode.

However, you may run into problems if you do not have administrator access on your work computer, as some command line tool installations may require admin/sudo access.